# Turn off vibration when docking the phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, vibration, docking-station

When I put my phone into the dock, it vibrates very strongly and for too long (IMO). Is it possible to turn that off or at least to decrease the intensity and/or duration of the vibration?

This is about a Samsung I9000 Galaxy S, with the Samsung ECR-D968BEG desktop dock/charger. The phone is running Android 2.3.3.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://lifehacker.com/5813093/vibration-notifier-makes-sure-that-you-dont-miss-important-email-and-sms-messages) app allows you to set duration of vibration

> Vibration Notifier Makes Sure that You
>   Don’t Miss Important Email and SMS
>   Messages

[This](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.twofortyfouram.locale.condition.dock&feature=search_result) app allows to have settings based on conditions such as in a dock

> > With Locale and the Dock Plug-in Condition, your phone can
> >     automatically perform actions based on
> >     whether it is docked in the car, desk,
> >     or undocked. Automatically launch an
> >     app with the Shortcut Plug-in when
> >     docked at home, enable Bluetooth in
> >     the car!

Answer (score -1):

[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) can also be used to perform actions based on conditions.

Comment: Can you expand on that? How, _exactly_, would one use Tasker to solve this problem?